# SQL Triggers for Delete and Insert too

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger that looks like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trSeasonHotelsSupplierOfferUpdate]
  ON  [dbo].[SeasonHotelsSupplierOffers]
  AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) = 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) = 1)
  BEGIN
       INSERT INTO SeasonHotelsSupplierOffersHistory (SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID, ColumnEN, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, UpdatedByID)
         SELECT 
            i.SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID, 'Name', d.Name, i.Name, i.UpdateDate, i.UpdatedByID 
         FROM 
            inserted i, deleted d       
         WHERE 
            ISNULL(i.Name,'')<>ISNULL(d.Name,'')
    END
END
```

I need to make this work for inserted data and deleted data too. This all saves into a table called SeasonHotelsSupplierOffersHistory that has these columns:

SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID, ColumnEN, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, UpdatedByID

I know that I have to say After Updated, Delete, Insert`, but that's about it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware your existing update trigger ignores update statements that affect multiple rows?

Comment: I can only update one row at a time, so it is ok

Comment: yes marc_s, very mature to downvote...at least bring arguments to your downvote. and I mean on topic arguments. not that you saw a letter or a font that you didn't like in my text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking as the only actual question appears to be how to get the trigger to work for INSERT and DELETE, but you have already answered this within your question. I can only assume you are struggling with getting the insert within the trigger to work for inserts and deletes to. I would imagine something like this would work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trSeasonHotelsSupplierOfferUpdate 
ON dbo.SeasonHotelsSupplierOffers
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT  SeasonHotelsSupplierOffersHistory (SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID, ColumnEN, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, UpdatedByID)
    SELECT  COALESCE(inserted.SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID, deleted.SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID),
            'Name', 
            deleted.Name, 
            inserted.Name, 
            COALESCE(inserted.UpdateDate, deleted.UpdateDate),
            COALESCE(inserted.UpdatedByID, deleted.UpdatedByID)
    FROM    inserted
            FULL JOIN deleted
                ON inserted.SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID = deleted.SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID
    WHERE   COALESCE(inserted.Name, '') != COALESCE(deleted.Name, '')   -- ONLY INSERT WHERE NAME HAS CHANGED
END
```

You will be able to identify inserts as `OldValue` will be null, and deletes as `NewValue` will be null.

Comment: perfect, exactly what I wanted. does the inserts in the history perfectly. THANKS! There is an issue thought and I don't think it has to do with it. I have a stored procedure for saving the record, and it returns the id of the inserted record, but now, since the trigger it returns the id of the last inserted reccord in the history table...any idea why this happens?

Comment: I found the problem: SET @SeasonHotelSupplierOfferID = (Select IDENT_CURRENT('SeasonHotelsSupplierOffers'))....it was @@Identity before, which brings the ID of the last identity on the current session